# Finding $\sum_{i=0}^n U_r$ for $U_r = \frac{r}{(\sqrt r +1)(\sqrt r +3)(\sqrt r +5)}$ where $r \in \Re$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you find the 
$\sum_{r=0}^n U_r$ where $U_r = \frac{r}{(\sqrt r +1)(\sqrt r +3)(\sqrt r +5)}$ where $r \in \Re$

In my knowledge I've ried breaking down itinto partial fraction considering a polynomial function for the numerator but then it asserts that $\sqrt r \in \Re$
which is not the case and using a polynomial function is invalid.

Is there a general way to solve such problems,if so please elaborate on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that even using special functions, we could get a closed form for
$$S_n=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{r}{(\sqrt r +1)(\sqrt r +3)(\sqrt r +5)}$$ As you did, using partiel fractions decomposition
$$\frac{r}{(\sqrt r +1)(\sqrt r +3)(\sqrt r +5)}=\frac{1}{8 \left(\sqrt{r}+1\right)}-\frac{9}{4 \left(\sqrt{r}+3\right)}+\frac{25}{8
   \left(\sqrt{r}+5\right)}$$ does not help in any manner.

However, the sum can be bounded by
$$T_n=\int_0^n \frac{r}{(\sqrt r +1)(\sqrt r +3)(\sqrt r +5)}\,dr$$
$$T_n=2 \sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\sqrt{n}+1\right)+\frac{27}{2} \log
   \left(\sqrt{n}+3\right)-\frac{125}{4} \log \left(\sqrt{n}+5\right)+\frac{125
   \log (5)}{4}-\frac{27 \log (3)}{2}$$ and
$$U_n=\int_1^{n+1} \frac{r}{(\sqrt r +1)(\sqrt r +3)(\sqrt r +5)}\,dr$$
$$U_n=2 \sqrt{n+1}-\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\sqrt{n+1}+1\right)+\frac{27}{2} \log
   \left(\sqrt{n+1}+3\right)-\frac{125}{4} \log
   \left(\sqrt{n+1}+5\right)-$$ $$2+\frac{125 \log (3)}{4}+\frac{9 \log (2)}{2}$$
Computing for a few values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & T_n & S_n & U_n \\
 10 & 0.37063 & 0.39120 & 0.40591 \\
 20 & 0.87289 & 0.89534 & 0.91172 \\
 30 & 1.39310 & 1.41579 & 1.43237 \\
 40 & 1.91284 & 1.93532 & 1.95166 \\
 50 & 2.42637 & 2.44846 & 2.46442 \\
 60 & 2.93165 & 2.95330 & 2.96882 \\
 70 & 3.42803 & 3.44923 & 3.46430 \\
 80 & 3.91546 & 3.93622 & 3.95085 \\
 90 & 4.39416 & 4.41449 & 4.42869 \\
 100 & 4.86444 & 4.88436 & 4.89815 \\
 200 & 9.18273 & 9.19947 & 9.21008 \\
 300 & 12.9876 & 13.0023 & 13.0108 \\
 400 & 16.4418 & 16.4550 & 16.4621 \\
 500 & 19.6359 & 19.6479 & 19.6538 \\
 600 & 22.6261 & 22.6372 & 22.6422 \\
 700 & 25.4504 & 25.4608 & 25.4650 \\
 800 & 28.1361 & 28.1458 & 28.1495 \\
 900 & 30.7034 & 30.7126 & 30.7157 \\
 1000 & 33.1679 & 33.1766 & 33.1792
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: If your to deduce the above series from a series where every "$\sqrt r$" term was replaced by a "$r$" term , is it mathematically valid to use substitution "when $r$ = $\sqrt r$ ...". ?